# Finding subsets from array

Tags: arrays, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Scenario : I want to count no. of subsets having negative numbers between two zeros. Here no. of subsets with negative numbers can be consider as travelling down the hill from sea level

Consider a array

```
a=[0,1,0,-1,-2,-l,0]
```

0 here represent sea level. Numbers between zeros are steps going up/down and is represent by positive/negative consecutive steps.
You can move any steps up/down but it should come to sea level before moving up/down

If you consider
`0,1,0` then it means that you moved from sea level to uphill and then again to sea level

```
0, 1, 0
```

similarly

From sea level to moving down one step, second step down, one step up and then again to sea level

```
0, -1, -2, -1, 0
```

Now considering an example.

```
 a=[0,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0]

 subset #1 = [0,1]
 subset #2 = [0,-1,-2,-1,0]
```

Output: `1` (One time travelling below sea level)

Consider another example

```
b = [0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2,1,0,-1,0]

subset #1 = [0,1,2,1,0] (moving up)
subset #2 = [0,-1,-2,-1,0] (moving down)
subset #3 = [0,1,2,1,0] (moving up)
subset #4 = [0,-1,0] (moving down)
```

Output: `2` (Two times travelling below sea level)

Comment: Can you explain why Example 1 subset 1 (your original example) is not `[0,1,0]` it seems to differ from all the other outputs. That being said I retracted my close vote as at least now there is context, albeit still a bit unclear to me due to the aforementioned idiosyncrasy.

Comment: Can you go from negative to positive without going through a zero?

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering if there's a reason that you couldn't just count the times that you have a zero followed by a negative number; something like:

```
def count_below(arr)
    count = 0
    arr.each_index do |i|
        count += 1 if arr[i] == 0 && (arr[i + 1] || 0) < 0
    end
    count
end
```

```
irb(main):039:0> count_below([0,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0])
=> 1
irb(main):040:0> count_below([0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2,1,0,-1,0])
=> 2
```

Comment: Yes i think it will work because i just need that only that

Comment: This counts `[0, -2, -1, -2, 0]` and `[0, -1, -2, 1, 0]`. My understand of the question is that neither should be counted, but if I am wrong (which is quite possible as the question is not clear), this is an excellent solution. My understood of the question is given in the first sentence of my answer. It is consistent with all the examples and with the reference to "uphill"? Rahul, you need to clarify the question (by editing it).

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**: Produce Desired "Output" (Number of times below "Sea Level")

*Assumptions*:

1. We start at or above Sea Level.

*Proposed Solution*:

```
b = [0,1,2,1,0,-1,-2,-1,0,1,2,1,0,-1,0]
b.each_cons(2).count {|a,b| !a.negative? && b.negative? }
```

*Steps*:

- Create an `Enumerator` of consecutive 2 elements (`b.each_cons(2)`)
- Count each time the first element is not negative and the second is negative (`count {|a,b| !a.negative? && b.negative? }`)

**Option 2:** To produce the slices in your question the following should work

*Assumptions*:

1. We always start at Sea Level (`0`)
2. One must touch Sea Level when ascending or descending (e.g. `[0,1,-1]` is considered invalid input)
3. The first example is incorrect and should be `[[0,1,0],[0,-1,-2,-1,0]]`

*Proposed Solution*:

```
b.each_cons(2).with_object([]) do |(a,b),obj|
  obj << [a] if a.zero?
  obj.last << b
end
#=> [[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, -1, -2, -1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, -1, 0]]
```

*Steps*:

- Create an `Enumerator` of consecutive 2 elements (`b.each_cons(2)`)
- Iterate with a Accumulator `Array` (`with_object([])`)
- Every time the first element is `0` insert a new sub `Array` (`obj << [a] if a.zero?`)
- Insert the second element into the current (last) sub `Array` (`obj.last << b`)
- `with_object` will return the accumulator `Array` as the result

<sub>You could chain methods to get the same result as Option 1 (such as `count {|a| a.any?(&:negative)}`)</sub>

Comment: Just curious; why doesn't `count {|a,b| a.zero? && b.negative? }` need the parentheses around `a,b`?

Comment: @BenStephens the parenthesis can be omitted because the parallel assignment is `a,b = [0,1]` in `each_with_object` the parens are needed because the assignment is `(a,b),obj = [[0,1],[]]` so it decomposes the outer Array and the inner Array. If they were omitted in the second case then the resulting assignment would be `a,b,obj = [[0,1],[]]` and `a == [0,1]; b == []; obj == nil`. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ummmmm, it probably does to people who aren't me. It seems like the argument to the block is one array with two elements and then Ruby magically says "you've asked for two arguments but there's only one so I'm gonna assume that you want me to dive into the array for ya" or something like that. Which, if true, I find quite disconcerting.

Comment: @BenStephens [Array Decomposition](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Array+Decomposition) and [Multiple Assignment](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.1.1/doc/syntax/assignment_rdoc.html#label-Multiple+Assignment)

Comment: Thanks engineersmnky, I genuinely dislike it. But I'll stop dragging you off topic now.

Answer (score 1):

My solution assumes that you wish to count the number of sub-arrays that begin and end with zero and from the initial zero  monotonically decrease to a minimum (negative) value, then monotonically increase to the final zero.

```
def count_em(arr)
  arr.flat_map.with_index { |e,i| (e.zero? && i > 0 && i < arr.size-1) ? [0,0] : [e] }
     .slice_when { |*pair| pair == [0,0] }
     .count { |a| downhill?(a) }
end
```

```
def downhill?(arr)
  return false if arr[1] > 0
  imin = arr.each_index.min_by { |i| arr[i] }
  return false unless decreasing?(arr[0..imin])
  decreasing?(arr[imin..-1].reverse)
end
```

```
def decreasing?(arr)
  arr.each_cons(2).all? { |e,f| f < e }
end
```

---

```
count_em [0, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0]
  #=> 1
count_em [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0]
  #=> 2
count_em [0, -2, -1, -2, 0]
  #=> 0
count_em [0, -1, -2, 1, 0]
  #=> 0
```

The last two examples reflect my understanding of the question.

---

The calculations are as follows.

```
arr = [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, -1, 0]
```

Use [Enumerable#flat_map](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) and [Enumerator#with_index](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerator.html#method-i-with_index) to insert a zero into a copy of `arr` after every zero but the first and last.

```
a = arr.flat_map.with_index { |e,i| (e.zero? && i > 0 && i < arr.size-1) ? [0,0] : [e] }
  #=> [0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, -1, -2, -1, 0, 0, 1, 2, 1, 0, 0, -1, 0]
```

We can now use [Enumerable#slice_when](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-slice_when) to obtain each sub-array that begins and end with a zero.

```
enum = a.slice_when { |*pair| pair == [0,0] }
  #=> #<Enumerator: #<Enumerator::Generator:0x00007fa9fd970f28>:each>
```

We can see the elements that will be generated by this enumerator by converting it to an array.

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, -1, -2, -1, 0], [0, 1, 2, 1, 0], [0, -1, 0]]
```

Lastly, use [Enumerable#count](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-count) to count the number of the four arrays generated by `enum` that are "downhill".

```
enum.count { |a| downhill?(a) }
  #=> 2
```

This is because

```
downhill? [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]     #=> false
downhill? [0, -1, -2, -1, 0]  #=> true
downhill? [0, 1, 2, 1, 0]     #=> false
downhill? [0, -1, 0]          #=> true
```

To see how `downhill?` works, let

```
arr = [0, -1, -2, -1, 0]
```

Then

```
arr[1] > 0
  #=> -1 > 0 => false, so do not return
imin = arr.each_index.min_by { |i| arr[i] }
  #=> 2
decreasing?(arr[0..imin])
  #=> decreasing? [0, -1, -2] => false, so do not return
decreasing?(arr[imin..-1].reverse)
  #=> decreasing? [-2, -1, 0].reverse => [0, -1, -2]
  #   decreasing? [0, -1, -2] => true
```

Let's now look at the calculations performed by `decreasing?`. Suppose

```
arr = [0, -1, -2]
```

We see that

```
enum = arr.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [0, -1, -2]:each_cons(2)>
```

`enum` generates the following arrays:

```
enum.to_a
  #=> [[0, -1], [-1, -2]]
```

Hence

```
arr.each_cons(2).all? { |e,f| f < e }
  #=> true
```

because `-1 < 0 #=> true` and `-2 < -1 #=> true`.